# Problems with SneakyInput on ARC

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, automatic-ref-counting

I am relatively new to Objective-C and I am starting to go through [SneakyInput](https://github.com/sneakyness/SneakyInput). I added it to the small app (it is ARC enabled) that I am making and when I ran the app it just crashed. I tried again, coding sneaky input for non ARC and it works perfectly.

This is the ARC version (where ARC is enabled), it crashes

```
- (void)initJoystick
{
    SneakyJoystickSkinnedBase *joystickBase;
    joystickBase.backgroundSprite = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"Icon-Small@2x.png"];
    joystickBase.thumbSprite = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"Icon-Small.png"];

    joystickBase.joystick = [[SneakyJoystick alloc] initWithRect: CGRectMake(0, 0, 128, 128)];

    joystickBase.position = ccp(55, 55);
    [self addChild:joystickBase];
}

- (id)init
{
    if( (self=[super init]) )
    {
        [self initJoystick];
    }
return self;
}

@end
```

This is the non ARC version, it doesn't crash

```
- (void)initJoystick
{
    SneakyJoystickSkinnedBase *joystickBase = [[[SneakyJoystickSkinnedBase alloc] init] autorelease];
    joystickBase.backgroundSprite = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"Icon-Small@2x.png"];
    joystickBase.thumbSprite = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"Icon-Small.png"];

    joystickBase.joystick = [[SneakyJoystick alloc] initWithRect: CGRectMake(0, 0, 128, 128)];

    joystickBase.position = ccp(55, 55);
    [self addChild:joystickBase];

    leftJoystick = [joystickBase.joystick retain];
}

-(id) init
{
    if( (self=[super init]) )
    {
        [self initJoystick];
    }
return self;
}

@end
```

I would like to continue in ARC with the rest of the app so I was wondering if anybody could tell me how to fix this so that it doesn't crash. Sorry if very noobie question.

This is the error message I get in outputs when ARC is enabled

```
2013-06-29 20:49:15.724 joystick[2135:12c03] *** Assertion failure in -[HelloWorldLayer addChild:], 
/Users/monagros/Desktop/Stuff/Cocos2D/apps/joystick/joystick/libs/cocos2d/CCNode.m:362
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the non-ARC version, you are setting `joystickBase` using alloc/init:

```
SneakyJoystickSkinnedBase *joystickBase = [[[SneakyJoystickSkinnedBase alloc] init] autorelease];
```

But in the ARC version of your code, you are not; you're leaving `joystickBase` as nil. The `addChild:` method is [checking for a nil value](https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-iphone/blob/develop-v2/cocos2d/CCNode.m#L380) for that object.

With ARC, you should initialize `joystickBase` like this:

```
SneakyJoystickSkinnedBase *joystickBase = [[SneakyJoystickSkinnedBase alloc] init];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can tell the compiler to not use arc for the sneaky input.

Click on your project and then click on your target. Choose build phases, and search for sneakyinput

When you find sneakyinput.m double click the white space in the space reserved for compiler flags. Then write this:

```
-fno-objc-arc
```

This method is good if you use non-arc features. I guess the sneakyinput is not ARC ready.

You then treat sneakyinput just like if it was arc enabled.

Comment: These per-file compiler flags may already be set because the app does compile and run, and just encounters a runtime exception that is not actually ARC related.

Comment: I see, well take it as a hint then :)